# WebSockets not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket, internet-explorer-10

I am using web sockets in a web application and they have stopped working in Internet Explorer, but after a little research no site with web sockets is working. Sites like twitter show the same error message in the IE console.

Here is the error:

```
SCRIPT12004: An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions
```

I have tried resetting all settings for IE and I have reset the web sockets according to this article:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/an-internal-error-occurred-in-the-microsoft/c3a186ac-4db0-46b5-b2ba-d134086bb293?msgId=47625912-31b8-44b7-be85-45562ac5767c

After trying everything I still can't find an answer or get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine?

Comment: I have rebooted several times

Comment: Is it just IE10? I'd just like to confirm it's an IE problem and not a Windows OS-level problem. Also, worth confirming you see the problem via this example: http://jsbin.com/ezojok/1/edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stumbled upon same issue today.

After some investigation it turned out that i have changed the browser and document mode of the rendering engine using Developer tools (F12).

Setting back document mode back to Standards fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This problem has been driving me nuts.  Document mode was on Edge (Default), tested and got 12004, set to IE 10, tested OK, set back to Edge (Default), tested OK.  Now I can't get it to fail, whereas before I couldn't get it to work.  Not convinced that this is the fix, but at least for today following the steps in this answer has cured the problem for this user.

Answer (score 0):

@ljubomir is right. Sometimes people do have IE 10 or 11, but their document mode is set to something lower which results in your `websocket` failing.

Set it to `10 or higher`, this will probably fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling the compatibility view.
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGTxp.png)